# How do I pass textbox values for this method argument?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have an Entity Model class named `BookMetaData.cs`. The class has three properties: `id`, `Name`, and `Price`. I also have a file `BookRepository.cs` with another class which has an `Add()` method to save a book to `myModel.edmx`.

Here's my `Add method:

```
private CRUDTestEntities db = new CRUDTestEntities();
       
public bool Add(CRUDTest.BOOK_TBL entity,bool autoSave = true)
{
    try
    {
        db.BOOK_TBL.Add(entity);
        if (autoSave)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have 3 textboxes in my form: `id`, `Name`, and `Price`. How can I pass the values from these textboxes to My `Add()` method?

I'm trying to call the method like this, but I'm not sure how to finish this code:

```
var blBook = new Repositories.BookRepository();
blBook.Add(/* There are two arguments in this method. How do I pass in textboxes?*/);
```

Comment: When do you want to call the method?

Comment: i make this Object 
'var blBook = new Repositories.BookRepository();'
and use my "blBook" Object
'blBook.Add(//THERE IS TWO ARGUMENT U CAN SEE IN MY ADD METHOD,how to passint text box's to here)'

Comment: Don't try to put details like that in a comment. Edit the question, so we can see your formatting.

Comment: Also, that tells me _how_ you call the method, but not _where_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the values from your textboxes to construct a new object matching the argument type for the method, which seems to be `CRUDTest.BOOK_TBL`. It'll look something like this:

```
var blBook = new Repositories.BookRepository();
var book = new CRUDTest.BOOK_TBL() {
    id = txtID.Text,
    Name = txtName.Text,
    Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text)
};

blBook.Add(book);
```